# Attach - Detach

Tags: gnu-screen, putty

I really don't know much about Linux but am forced to copy some data onto a RAID over a Linux server as the person responsible isn't available.

It seems as the process has stopped. I don't know whether I have stopped it. The process is attached. Meaning it was stopped or not? Why can I not resume it? I tried to detach it but that doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

```
root@phenomen01:/usr/local/bin# screen -r 9603.pts-0.phenomen01
There is a screen on:
        9603.pts-0.phenomen01   (11/20/2014 09:11:58 PM)        (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 9603.pts-0.phenomen01.


root@phenomen01:/usr/local/bin# screen -d
[9603.pts-0.phenomen01 detached.]
```

Comment: please reformat the output so it's readable.  Can you add details on how the data is copied?  Which tool/commands are used?  How is it scheduled or triggered?  Could it be you are already connected to the screen session and as such cannot attach to the session a second time?

Answer (score 0):

"Attached" / "detached" refers to the virtual `screen` console, not to the copy process.

If there is one `screen` session only then the easiest way to get it back is:

```
screen -x
```

If there are several ones then the above command gives you their names.

If the process running in `screen` (usually a shell) exits then the `screen` console is closed.